# How can I use AzD/Azure Developer CLI environment values in my script?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

`AzD` shows me values like these after my deployment:

```bash
$ azd env get-values
...
AZURE_CONTAINER_REGISTRY_ENDPOINT="contreg.azurecr.io"
AZURE_CONTAINER_REGISTRY_NAME="contreg"
SERVICEBUS_ENDPOINT="https://sb.servicebus.windows.net:443/"
SERVICE_TESTDATA_IMAGE_NAME="contreg.azurecr.io/test-data/test-data:azdev-deploy-1665835078"
TESTDATA_URI="https://test-data.nicedune-eccf12fx.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io"
```

How can I get e.g. `TESTDATA_URI` in a bash script to work with the endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output from `azd env get-values` can be piped into **source** statement to have these values available:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source <(azd env get-values)

curl -X POST "$TESTDATA_URI/api/Generate"
```